# Unable to upload images from Ruby to Wordpress using XMLRPC - damaged image

Tags: ruby, wordpress

I am using a gem called rubypress to post content from ruby to wordpress using XMLRPC. Everything is working except for the image uploading part. I converted the image to base64 encoded format but after upoloading, all i get is a grey image and not the one that i had intended to upload(I am using smaller images around 100kb size to upload for testing). What I am i doing wrong?
Here's the code from rubypress github page(https://github.com/zachfeldman/rubypress) for uploading:

```
FILENAME='myFile.png'
wp.uploadFile(:data => {
    :name => FILENAME,
    :type => MIME::Types.type_for(FILENAME).first.to_s,
    :bits => XMLRPC::Base64.new(IO.read(FILENAME))
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to solve it by changing the Base64 encoding code as follows:

```
$wp.uploadFile(:data => {
    :name => File.basename(imgname),
    :type => MIME::Types.type_for(imgname).first.to_s,
    :bits => XMLRPC::Base64.new(File.open(FILENAME,"rb").read),
    :post_id =>postid

    })
```

The file apparently needs to be "opened" first rather than be read using IO.read(FILENAME).

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
wp.uploadFile(:data => {:name => File.basename(FILENAME),
                   :type => MIME::Types.type_for(FILENAME).first.to_s,
                   :bits => XMLRPC::Base64.new(File.open(FILENAME).read)
})
```

Comment: thanks Mike, i tried this but same. I get a grey invalid image. does this have to do with the version of ruby i am using? I am using 2.1.0

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, have you tried displaying the image prior to the upload? Regarding specific versions of Ruby do you have [RVM](https://rvm.io/) installed? You can try it yourself. PS. Don't use admin privileges (it defeats the purpose). Install RVM in your home directory.

Comment: Hi Mike, Yeah its a valid image. When i try with a simple php script that uses xmlrpc to upload to wordpress, it works. I am using [RailFTW](http://railsftw.bryanbibat.net/) which is a rails installer. I will give RVM a try but i think the problem might not be related to ruby version. I also tried `:bits=>Base64.strict_encode64(IO.binread(FILENAME))` but its the same. Do you think it could be due to my particular ruby version?

Comment: Which gem [xml-rpc](https://rubygems.org/gems/wordpress-xmlrpc) do you have installed? Which version of that gem?  Certainly some version of xml-rpc works with Ruby 2.1.. Looking through the various [xml-rpc gems](https://rubygems.org/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=xmlrpc), none of the latest versions specify a required Ruby version.

Comment: Ruby 2.1.0 itself contains module [XMLRPC](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/XMLRPC/CGIServer.html).

Comment: Thanks for your help @Mike. i was finally able to solve it. The file needs to be opened first before "reading" it. Not sure if this works in Linux but this works fine in Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my way of doing it, works pretty well:

```
image = MiniMagick::Image.open(this_image.path)
image.format('jpg')
image.combine_options do |c|
  c.strip
end
image.write(this_image.path)

# most efficient resize as suggested by https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/06/efficient-image-resizing-with-imagemagick/
MiniMagick::Tool::Mogrify.new do |mogrify|
  mogrify.filter('Triangle')
  mogrify.define('filter:support=2')
  mogrify.thumbnail('960x')
  mogrify.unsharp('0.25x0.08+8.3+0.045')
  mogrify.dither('None')
  mogrify.posterize('136')
  mogrify.quality('82')
  mogrify.define('jpeg:fancy-upsampling=off')
  mogrify.interlace('none')
  mogrify.colorspace('sRGB')
  mogrify << this_image.path
end


type = image.mime_type
bits = XMLRPC::Base64.new(IO.read(this_image.path))

begin
  result = wp.uploadFile(
           data: {
               name: image_name,
               type: type,
               bits: bits,
               post_id: post_id,
               overwrite: true
           })
rescue StandardError => e 
  puts e
end
```